# HOG feature based recognition

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network

**scene**

I used haar cascade to detect face and that face ROI was passed to estimate its HoG feature...while calculating HoG feature...I used 8x8 patch of image(assuring all image was a square matrix).

**problem**

I used to create a 9 bin histogram for each patch.for example for a image ROI of 177x177 dimension I obtain 484 8x8 patch...out of all each patch contains a 9 bin histogram(9-dimension vector)...So for whole image I obtain total 4356 catenated histogram( 4356 dimension vector..)...Now I usually don't want to apply PCA algorithm currently or any kind of dimension reduction..The **problem** is a single image is generating such a large dimensional vector what if I feed 5 image to network (also dimension is changing with picture...its not fixed!)..feels like BooM!!
so what to do..